# text input only takes one digit or multiple identical digits

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js and would like to create a input field component that only takes positive integers (0 is fine too). I would like to avoid using regex to keep it human readable :)

My consuming parent component passes in the current value and uses the shorthand sync directive

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <positive-integer-input :value.sync="currentValue" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PositiveIntegerInput from "../components/PositiveIntegerInput.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    "positive-integer-input": PositiveIntegerInput
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentValue: 0
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The input component itself is just a basic text input (for better CSS styling)

```
<template>
  <input :id="_uid" type="text" :value="value" @input="onInput" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput({ data }) {
      const inputNumber = Number(data);

      if (!Number.isInteger(inputNumber) || inputNumber < 0) {
        const input = document.getElementById(this._uid);
        input.value = this.value;
      } else {
        this.$emit("update:value", inputNumber);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Whenever the input changes I'm validating the incoming input for positive integers. If that validation fails I want to reset the current input field content (maybe there is a more userfriendly solution?)

The input field itself only takes one digit or multiple identical digits. So only these are possible:

- 3
- 4
- 333333
- 4444

but not:

- 34

Does someone know how to fix the component?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any error in the console ?

Comment: @question3r, I have made an update to my answer. Can your check it?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. Which aspects of your desired behaviour currently aren't working? Are you asking how to add a condition that ensures all the digits are the same? If so, what would be the expectations around 0? It seems a little arbitrary to rule out using a RegExp. Correctly used a RegExp can be significantly easier to read than the alternative.

Comment: @ Nipun Jain no there are no errors

Comment: @ webprogrammer I'll answer below your answer

Comment: @ skirtle I would like to create an input taking positive integer values only. Meaning only the digits "0123456789"

Comment: @Question3r, don't put a space between "@" and username. It break notification to user. I didn't get notification from you because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand the requirements but I think this is somewhere close to what you're looking for:

```js
const PositiveIntegerInput = {
  template: `
    <input
      ref="input"
      type="text"
      :value="value"
      @input="onInput"
    >  
  `,

  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onInput(ev) {
      const value = ev.target.value;
      const inputNumber = parseInt(value, 10);

      if (inputNumber >= 0 && String(inputNumber) === value) {
        this.$emit('update:value', inputNumber);
      } else {
        // Reset the input if validation failed
        this.$refs.input.value = this.value;
      }
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    PositiveIntegerInput
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      currentValue: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form>
      <positive-integer-input :value.sync="currentValue" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `$refs` instead of `document.getElementById` to perform the reset.

To check the input is an integer I've simply converted it to an integer using `parseInt`, then converted it back to a string and compared that to the original string.

There are several edge cases that could cause problems. A particularly obvious one is that the input can never be empty, which makes changing an existing value quite difficult. However, as far as I can tell, this does meet the requirements given in the question.

**Update:**

A few notes on number parsing.

Using `Number(value)` will return `NaN` if it can't parse the entire string. There are some quirks with using `Number` too. e.g. Try `Number('123e4')`, `Number('0x123')` or `Number('0b11')`.

Using `parseInt(value, 10)` will parse as many characters as it can and then stop. `parseInt` also has some quirks but by explicitly specifying a radix of `10` they mostly go away.

If you try to parse `'53....eeöööööö'` using `parseInt` you'll get `53`. This is an integer, so it'll pass a `Number.isInteger` test.

Personally I'd like to have used a RegExp to ensure the string only contains digits 0-9 before doing any further manipulation. That quickly helps to eliminate a whole load of possible edge cases such that they wouldn't need any further consideration. Something like `/^\d*$/.test(value)`, or the converse `!/\D/.test(value)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I checked your snippet and updated my code to yours https://hatebin.com/hjofnpgbjw When I comment out your solution below and use mine, the code is not working properly, so `53....eeöööööö` is still valid... Do you know why?

Comment: because your solution still makes `-123` possible :)

Comment: @Question3r Indeed. I have updated my answer to prevent minus signs.

Comment: thanks for your update. But I still would like to know the difference between `String(inputNumber) === value` and `Number.isInteger(inputNumber)` .. but the integer check fails

Comment: @Question3r I've added a further update to the end that may help to clarify.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. Based on your regex I think this should do the trick? https://hatebin.com/neoyhejkoh

Comment: @Question3r That depends on the requirements. You'll need to check how it handles leading zeroes, as well as an empty value.

Comment: it ignores leading zeros and ye ... the field may not be empty unfortunately. But I think I can deal with it :)

Comment: I tried to improve your solution with a new answer, maybe this will help someone :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031080/7764329

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
const input = document.getElementById(this._uid);
input.value = this.value;
```

Use `v-model` instead or try to replace code by this:

```
<template>
  <input :id="_uid" type="text" :value="inputValue" @input="onInput($event.target.value, $event)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return inputValue: 0,
  },
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.inputValue = this.value;
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(value, event) {
      const inputNumber = Number(value);

      if (!Number.isInteger(inputNumber) || inputNumber < 0) {
        this.inputValue = this.value;
      } else {
        this.$emit("update:value", inputNumber);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. but I shouldn't use a `v-model` because I'm using a prop-emit event flow. And the second solution would break this flow completely, no?

Comment: @Question3r, Using `document.getElementById(this._uid);` definitely isn't a vue-way.

Comment: @Question3r, you still have `this.$emit("update:value", inputNumber);` in my code instead of using `v-model`.

Comment: yes I tested your example. I can paste in every character I want so there is no protection anymore

Comment: @Question3r, I accidentally have deleted `onInput` method from input. Can you check my code once more?

Comment: Yes, np. I tested it and can still put in every character I want. For example "232342332323......aadsasdasd+++++". The code I used https://hatebin.com/eioqdriupu I think this happens because of the broken data flow when using the created hook

Comment: @Question3r, Can you show me how do you include that component into your app?  Do you see some errors in the console?

Comment: The first code block shows how I consume that component. I get no errors

Comment: @Question3r, oh, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I tried to improve Skirtles answer. So the component consumer remains the same, only the input component changes a little bit. Now it's possible to leave the input empty but the value won't trigger an update then. Also the input field adds some visual styles based on the validation.

```
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    :value="value"
    @input="onInput"
    :class="[inputValueIsValid ? 'valid-input' : 'invalid-input']"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      digitsOnlyRegex: /^\d*$/,
      inputValueIsValid: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.validateInputValue(this.value);
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(inputEvent) {
      const currentInputValue = inputEvent.target.value;
      this.validateInputValue(currentInputValue);

      if (this.inputValueIsValid) {
        const inputNumber = parseInt(currentInputValue, 10);
        this.$emit("update:value", inputNumber);
      }
    },
    validateInputValue(currentInputValue) {
      const isNotEmpty = currentInputValue.toString().length > 0;
      const containsDigitsOnly = this.digitsOnlyRegex.test(currentInputValue);
      this.inputValueIsValid = isNotEmpty && containsDigitsOnly;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.valid-input {
  background: green;
}

.invalid-input {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```